# Using Travis-CI for Node.js project

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

I'm trying to set up travis-ci for my node.js project hosted on github. For some reason travis  keeps using ruby worker for building/testing the project.

My .travis.yml looks like:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
    - 0.6

script: 
    - "make test"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK got it. 
The `.travis.yml` file must not contain 'tab' characters. Instead I have replaced them with spaces.